# How to align lines of string/characters in python

Tags: python, string, format, character

A simplified version of my problem is as follows. The current code/output I have is problematic.

Code:

```
file.write("AAAA" + "\n")
file.write(num + " BBBBB") #num is a random number
```

Current output:

```
AAAAA
20 BBBBB
```

I would like to align the A's and B's so that it looks like this:

```
   AAAAA
20 BBBBB
```

Specifically though, I need the output to work for any number. I.e, "2000BBBB" etc.

Making it work for the example I have given is easy enough, I could just add spacing. The problem here is writing code that will essentially predict where the second line's B's will be located.

I hope that makes sense, thank you.

Comment: Maybe something like `len(num) * " "` i.e. len(num) * space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
first = "AAAA" + "\n"
second = str(num) + " BBBBB"
file.write(first.rjust(len(second)))
file.write(second)
```

Check those: [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) for `rjust()` and [w3schools tutorial with examples](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_rjust.asp) for `rjust()`

Comment: Thank you very much...you're a life saver. this will be very helpful; appreciate it. :)